# How to calculate Lebesgue integral in this type?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

For Lebesgue integral in this type, like$$\int_\pi^\infty \left({1 \over {x \sin^{1/3}x} }\right)^2$$ can anyone give me some general idea?
I don't know use which inequalities to start with the this one.

Comment: $\log\cos x$ is not defined on all of $(1,\infty)$, since we have $\cos x<0$ frequently.

Comment: ohyes，i fixed it, but how to do the first one?

Comment: The first one looks to be problematic since there are many places where $\sin(x)=0$. Are you sure of the bounds ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes,  the bounds are correct for the first integral.

Comment: Why deface the question?

Comment: @Did Oh! I was trying to test different Latex code from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you only want to show that the integral is finite, not calculate the precise value.

I would do the following:
$$
\int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 \cdot \sin^{2/3}(x)} /, dx =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{1}{x^2 \cdot \sin^{2/3}(x) }\, dx \asymp \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-2}  \int_0^\pi \sin^{-2/3}(x)\,dx <\infty.
$$

Here, I used $\pi$-periodicity of $\sin^2$. Finally, the final integral should be finite, since $\sin (x) \sim x$ near $0$ and $\int x^{-2/3}\, dx<\infty$. The blowup at $\pi$ can be handled d similarly. I leave the details to you.

A similar approach will work for similar integrals.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really works. Once I know your approach, I can do a lot problems in this type now. Thanks again!